# How to avoid double quote when using export-csv in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a file data.csv which contains:

```
2017.11.1,09:55,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1 
2017.11.2,09:55,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,2
```

I want to filter it by yesterday date so I did this:

```
$Data = Import-Csv $file -Header Date,Time,A,B,C,D,E
$CutOff = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$Data2 = $Data | Where-Object {$_.Date -as [datetime] -gt $Cutoff}
$Data2 | Export-Csv -Path "Date2.csv"
```

But file data2.csv contains:

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"Date","Time","A","B","C","D","E"
"2017.11.2","09:55","1.5","1.6","1.7","1.8","2"
```

Which is not the same format than the original one:

- How to get rid of double quotes
- How to get rid of the header and type lines

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f6b610b6-bfb2-4140-9529-e61ad30b8927/how-to-export-csv-without-doublequote?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: This is also useful: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/02/remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-from-csv-files-by-using-powershell/ Good question by the way.

Comment: `Export-Csv -Path "Date2.csv" -NoTypeInformation` will remove the Type line